# MySQL fulltext search with apostrophe doesn’t return expected result

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, innodb, apostrophe

I’m running MySQL 5.6.24 with InnoDB and attempting to implement a fulltext search.  I have a list of restaurant names and testing  seemed to be working well until I tried the following.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('grill\'d' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I have the restaurant called Grill’d in the database spelt exactly that way (with apostrophe).  I also have plenty of restaurants in the table with the word Grill in the title.  The search returns both Grill’d and all those with Grill in the title.  This wouldn’t be so bad if it gave Grill’d a higher relevance, but it does not.

On further investigation it would appear that \’ is being replaced with a space as the search ‘steak\’house’ returns all names that include the word ‘steak’ or ‘house’ but NOT ‘steakhouse’.

Can anyone provide some advice on this but perhaps more importantly how I get just Grill’d returned as a result.

UPDATE

'"p\'tite*"'    does find P'tite (OK)

'"p\'tit*"'     does NOT find P'tite (why not ?)

'p\'ti*'        does find P'tite but also finds Tiger, Tim, etc (why, it should only find P'tite ?)

"p\'ti*"        does find P'tite but also finds Tiger, Tim, etc (why ?)

"p'ti*"         does find P'tite but also finds Tiger, Tim, etc  (why ?)

Any advice on delimiters and wildcards?

Comment: `FULLTEXT` is less than perfect.  Are you using MyISAM?  Or InnoDB?

Comment: I'm using InnoDB with MySQL 5.6.24 as mentioned in the question.  I state the exact MySQL version as I'm aware there was a bug that related to apostrophes in, I believe, 5.6 pre .13 releases.